# The console prints a list of items for the user to scroll through using the up and down arrow keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am somewhat new to python (yes I know, a cliché statement) and I wrote this code to scroll through a tuple of strings using the arrow keys. I know that the code is sloppy but I don't know how. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
import keyboard
from os import system
from time import sleep


class Menu:
    def __init__(self, *items):
        self.items = items
        self.selections = 6
        self.start = 0
        self.stop = self.start + self.selections
        self.slice = items[self.start:self.stop]
        self.selected = 0
        self.beg = '>'
        self.end = '<'

    def get_input(self):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
            if self.selected >= 0:
                self.selected += -1
            self.show()
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
            if self.selected < self.selections:
                self.selected += +1
            self.show()

    def show(self):
        system('cls')

        # shift slice up if the bottom of list is reached
        if self.selected == self.selections:
            if self.stop < len(self.items):
                self.start += 1
                self.stop += 1
                self.slice = self.items[self.start:self.stop]
            self.selected = self.selections-1

        # shift slice down if top of list is reached
        elif self.selected < 0:
            if self.start > 0:
                self.start += -1
                self.stop += -1
                self.slice = self.items[self.start:self.stop]
            self.selected = 0

        # print the slice with the selected item printed like >this<
        for i in range(len(self.slice)):
            if i == self.selected:
                print(self.beg + self.slice[i] + self.end)
            else:
                print(self.slice[i])


test_menu = Menu('item 0',
                 'item 1',
                 'item 2',
                 'item 3',
                 'item 4',
                 'item 5',
                 'last item')
test_menu.show()


while 1:
    test_menu.get_input()
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: this works only on windows, since linux doesn't have a cls command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should organise the code in such way that each function performs one function (hence the name ;)) and what it does should be what its name says. For example, `show` should be printing (i.e. showing) the menu, not modifying internal state.

Only this fits in:

```
def show(self):
    system('cls')

    # print the slice with the selected item printed like >this<
    for i, item in enumerate(self.slice):
        if i == self.selected:
            print(self.beg + item + self.end)
        else:
            print(item)
```

The rest should be done in the function which handles moving up or down.

That said, I would change `get_input` as well, to something like this:

```
def process_input(self):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
        self.move_cursor(-1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
        self.move_cursor(1)
```

And then:

```
def move_cursor(self, offset):
    self.selected = min(max(self.selected + offset, 0), self.selections-1)

    # handle moving the slice here

    self.show()
```

I hope I got that `min`/`max` limit right :)

Comment: BTW, is there need to have `beg` , `end` and `selections` as attributes? I would hard-code `beg` and `end` and have `print(f'>{item}<1')`

Comment: This helps a lot. I didn't think to put move cursor in it's own function. That does look cleaner. I don't know what you did with min/max functions lol, but I can either figure that out or find another way to do it. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2):

`get_input` should be called `handle_input`. `get_input` suggests that it returns input values, whereas really, it's a "step" function used to handle what's going on at a slice in time.

Also in that function, `self.selected += -1` is confusing. Why add a negative number instead of subtracting? I would change that and the other similar instances to `self.selected -= 1`. Personally, I'd also get rid of the prefix `+` in `+1`. I don't find it adds anything.

---

Sorry, I wrote another review before this and my brain's tired. Hopefully someone else can give better suggestions.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback! Naming does seem to be my biggest hurdle.

Comment: @RobertAlvies To be fair, naming is hard. I'll rename a finction many times before I'm finally happy with it.